# Can't run make using C++ stdlib system call

Tags: c++, makefile, std

I've got the following code in C++

```
  if (should_run_make) {
    std::string make = "make -C ";
    make.append(outdir);
    std::cout << "Make cmd is " << make << std::endl;
    system(make.c_str());
  }
```

This reports the following:

> Make cmd is make -C /home/hamiltont/temp/ make: Entering directory
>   `/home/hamiltont/temp' make: *** No targets.  Stop.
>   make: Leaving directory`/home/hamiltont/temp'

However, doing it manually works fine in multiple ways e.g.

```
[hamiltont@4 generator]$ make -C /home/hamiltont/temp/
make: Entering directory `/home/hamiltont/temp'
g++ -O3 -I/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -lmpi -lmpi_cxx -lboost_serialization -lboost_mpi  stg_impl.cpp -o impl
make: Leaving directory `/home/hamiltont/temp'

[hamiltont@4 generator]$ cd /home/hamiltont/temp/
[hamiltont@4 temp]$ make
g++ -O3 -I/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -lmpi -lmpi_cxx -lboost_serialization -lboost_mpi  stg_impl.cpp -o impl
```

Comment: I have a feeling the problem is that you have some extra junk somewhere that isn't visible, which makes `all` into a string that isn't matching your target `all`. Try printing each character in your string `make.c_str()`.

Comment: Completely removed the term `all' and I'm seeing the same behavior. Question updated to match

Comment: @MatsPetersson, i dont know, wouldn't it fail to enter the directory, or throw a bad command call if this was the case, not just no make file found?

Comment: Make sure that you are not using any shell functions or aliases. `type make` should work.

Comment: I suspect it's an environment problem.  The PATH could be different for the shell invoked by `system()`... you could try `system("which make")` and compare to the manual output from your shell.  You might also try checking for shell environment variables, aliases, functions that customise the behaviour of make, providing extra flags or changing behaviours.

Comment: @Ben @Hamy: It was saying `no target all`. I just tried typing `make -C someplace-with-a-makefile all` in a shell, and that does what is described above.

Comment: Try using the full path to make in both the shell and the system() call. See if that acts differently.

Comment: Also try adding the `-d` flag to make in your system() call. Should produce a pile of debug output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you generating the makefile from within your C program?  That's the only reason I could imagine would cause that specific error message.

```
make: *** No targets. Stop.
```

### Reproducing the error

Here's how I could generate that message:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("Makefile", "w");
    fputs("all:\n\techo Done.\n", fp);
    system("make");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

This, predictably, prints:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

I say predictably because `Makefile` will be empty!  This is because IO is buffered...

### Fixed version

So, I close the file before calling `system()`, which flushes the buffer (`fflush()` would also do the trick):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("Makefile", "w");
    fputs("all:\n\techo Done.\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);
    system("make");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
echo Done.
Done.
```

I used C's IO functions for clarity, but the same rules apply to `<iostream>`.

Comment: I was using std::ofstream to build the Makefile, and I had followed advice elsewhere that letting the destructor close the stream was better than calling close manually :-). Manually calling close fixed the issue!

Comment: @Hamy: As another option, you can still use the destructor to close the file if you surround the code with braces `{ ... }` and make the stream a block-scope variable.